# visual studio ultimate preview 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I wanted to ask that if I download Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Preview, will it need to be paid for when visual studio 2013 is released, or will this 2013 preview of Ultimate will become disabled etc? Or will it remain free to use?

Regards.

Comment: But when final product comes i.e. Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate then this preview will remain as it is or will be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want visual studio 2013 you need to pay for it. The preview remain a preview.

Comment: Glad to help, I will try visual studio 2013 too.